# Object not found Yii2 Reportico

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

After installing Reportico on Yii2, I'm having a problem accessing the Reportico it says "Object not found".

Here's the code:

```
<li><a href="/reportico"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Generate Reports</a></li>
```

I also followed the instruction on their github and says access it here:

```
http://yii2_url/index.php/r=reportico or (http://yii2_url/index.php/reportico
```

But it just redirects me on my index page.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it I was wrong on my link

The fix is:

```
<li><a href="index.php?r=reportico"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Generate Reports</a></li>
```

Comment: Start using `Url::to()`. Try imagine what will happen if you change URL's to prettyUrl.

Comment: I see, I will change the config now.